# How do I define the @param callback {Function}'s expected parameters in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea, jsdoc

I use a lot of callbacks and I want the editor to detect the type of function callback that is expected by the method, with a specific nr of parameters of specific types.

Right now it just says Function and it can be anything but I want to make it specific, this in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellij (and the family of editors) support the **[Google Closure Compiler syntax](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler)**.

So you'd do something like this:

```
/**
 * @param {function(Number, String)} bar
 */
function foo(bar) {};
```

Note the lowercase `f` in `function`.